MariaDB monitoring not possible with Nagios and check_procs
I have a problem with nagios supervision. I would like to check that MariaDB is running on my web server, but Nagios returns "CRITICAL PROCESSES: 0 processes with command name 'mariadbd'".
Here is my Nagios configuration:
define service {
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               p8_client
    service_description     Checking MariaDB
    check_command           chk_procs!1:!mariadbd
}

define command {
    command_name    chk_procs
    command_line    $USER1$/check_procs -c $ARG1$ -C $ARG2$
}

And here is what my web server returns to me:
user@debian11:~$ ps aux | grep mariadbd
mysql        606  0.0  4.8 1544548 98320 ?       Ssl  17:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/mariadbd
user        3193  0.0  0.0   6284   640 pts/0    S+   17:38   0:00 grep mariadbd

Thank you in advance for your help.

Have you try to exec from command line something like: check_procs -c 1: -C mariadbd and check the result. Also -v in above command may give more information

Is your Nagios host the same as your web server p8_client? Because you run this check on your nagios host. You would need nrpe or something other way to query other servers if your mariadb is not on nagios host.
